# Object is dark when in Cycles and in Eevee when I turn on AO even though lighting is plenty in the scene

Tags: gltf

I am trying to figure out why the model I imported is dark. It is a .glb file which I have imported. I usually do not have this problem with .obj files.

The object looks correct when the AO is turned off in eevee but when it is turned on OR I switch to Cycles, it goes dark.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, check normals orientation, if displayed red, flip them *(in Edit Mode)* with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> > *Flip*

[image: Face Orientation]

Second, I would try going to *Object Data Properties* and under *Geometry* Tab check if ***Clear Custom Normals*** button is available. Sometimes it causes shading errors.

[image: Object Data Properties]

Comment: Thanks a lot Jan! The Clear Custom Normals button did the trick.
Dzieki! <3